# How to generate random Email Address via. Stored Procedure or Function in SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, t-sql

I am new to T-SQL and I have one requirement where I have generate millions of unique random fake Email Ids in SQL server using a Function or a Stored Procedure.

Using JAVA, I have created one program which can generate 50 unique email ids (mentioned below) but I wanted the same in SQL server.

Could you please assist me how to implement using T-SQL? Any help would be appreciated.

```
package com.ing.tdm;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;

public class EmailGenerator {

    public static String getEmailDomains(){
         String randomElement = "";
        String strOfEmailDomains = "aol.com, att.net, comcast.net, facebook.com, gmail.com, gmx.com, googlemail.com, google.com, hotmail.com, hotmail.co.uk, mac.com, me.com, mail.com, msn.com, live.com, sbcglobal.net, verizon.net, yahoo.com, yahoo.co.uk, email.com, fastmail.fm, games.com, gmx.net, hush.com, hushmail.com, icloud.com, iname.com, inbox.com, lavabit.com, love.com , outlook.com, pobox.com, protonmail.com, rocketmail.com, safe-mail.net, wow.com , ygm.com , ymail.com, zoho.com, yandex.com, bellsouth.net, charter.net, cox.net, earthlink.net, juno.com, btinternet.com, virginmedia.com, blueyonder.co.uk, freeserve.co.uk, live.co.uk, ntlworld.com, o2.co.uk, orange.net, sky.com, virgin.net, wanadoo.co.uk, bt.com, sina.com, sina.cn, qq.com, naver.com, hanmail.net, daum.net, nate.com, yahoo.co.jp, yahoo.co.kr, yahoo.co.id, yahoo.co.in, yahoo.com.sg, yahoo.com.ph, 163.com, 126.com, aliyun.com, foxmail.com, hotmail.fr, live.fr, laposte.net, yahoo.fr, wanadoo.fr, orange.fr, gmx.fr, sfr.fr, neuf.fr, free.fr, gmx.de, hotmail.de, live.de, online.de, t-online.de , web.de, yahoo.de, libero.it, virgilio.it, hotmail.it, aol.it, tiscali.it, alice.it, live.it, yahoo.it, email.it, tin.it, poste.it, teletu.it, mail.ru, rambler.ru, yandex.ru, ya.ru, list.ruhotmail.be, live.be, skynet.be, voo.be, tvcablenet.be, telenet.be, hotmail.com.ar, live.com.ar, yahoo.com.ar, fibertel.com.ar, speedy.com.ar, arnet.com.ar, yahoo.com.mx, live.com.mx, hotmail.es,yahoo.com.ar, fibertel.com.ar, speedy.com.ar, arnet.com.ar, yahoo.com.mx, live.com.mx, hotmail.es, hotmail.com.mx, prodigy.net.mx, yahoo.com.br, hotmail.com.br, outlook.com.br, uol.com.br, bol.com.br, terra.com.br, ig.com.br, itelefonica.com.br, r7.com, zipmail.com.br, globo.com, globomail.com, oi.com.br";
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(strOfEmailDomains, ",");
        Random rand = new Random();

        List<String> givenList = new ArrayList<String>();

        while(st.hasMoreElements()){
            String emaildomain = (String) st.nextElement();
            givenList.add(emaildomain);
        }

        if(null!=givenList && givenList.size() > 0){
            int randomIndex = rand.nextInt(givenList.size());
              randomElement = givenList.get(randomIndex);
        }

        return randomElement;

    }


public static String generateRandomEmail(int length) {
    String emailId = "";
    String allowedChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" + "1234567890";
    String allowedSpecialChars = "_-.";

    String temp = RandomStringUtils.random(length, allowedChars);
    emailId = (temp.substring(0, temp.length() - 9)
            +Character.toString((RandomStringUtils.random(length, allowedSpecialChars)).charAt(0))
            +temp.substring(12, 18)
            +"@"+getEmailDomains()).replaceAll("\\s","");

    System.out.println(emailId);
    return emailId;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        generateRandomEmail(20);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Doing this directly in t-sql is not a great approach. SQL is designed for handling sets of data, not generating random data. Sure it can be done but it is convoluted and slow to do this in t-sql. Since you already have code that can do this why do you need to recreate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i came up with a much more difficult solution but I think it suits your needs better.

I have three temp tables:

- emailDomain a list of all domains with ids
- allowedChar a list of all chars with ids
- allowedSpecialChar a list of all special chars with ids

After i have created the tables I generate with a recursive cte 50 rows (you can do more if you want to) with random email lengths and an mailid. Then I generate for every char in the mail an random id in the ranche of the  ids in the allowedChar table. Then I join the allowedChar table with the generated id and concat the singe chars with "for xml path" in a single row.
For the emailDomain and allowedSpecialChar i do it pretty much the same way. To the end i concat everything to a valid E-Mail address.

```
--setup emailDomain table
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#emailDomain') is not NULL
    drop table #emailDomain

create table #emailDomain (
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    domain varchar(50) not null
)

insert into #emailDomain
--id is automatic generated
values('aol.com')
     ,('att.net')
     ,('comcast.net')
     ,('facebook.com')
     ,('gmail.com')
     ,('gmx.com')

--setup allowedChar table
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#allowedChar') is not NULL
    drop table #allowedChar

create table #allowedChar(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    aChar char(1) not null
)

insert into #allowedChar
values('a'),('b'),('c'),('d'),('e'),('f'),('g'),('h'),('i'),('j'),('k'),('l'),('m'),('n'),('o'),('p'),('q')
,('r'),('s'),('t'),('u'),('v'),('w'),('x'),('y'),('z'),('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('9'),('7'),('0'),('8')

--setup allowedSpecialChar table
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#allowedSpecialChar') is not NULL
    drop table #allowedSpecialChar

create table #allowedSpecialChar(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    asChar char(1)
)

insert into #allowedSpecialChar
VALUES('_'),('-'),('.')

declare @countDomains as int = (select count(*) from #emailDomain)
declare @countallowedChars as int = (select count(*) from #allowedChar)
declare @countallowedSpecialChars as int = (select count(*) from #allowedSpecialChar);

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#rowsWithRandomCharsNrs') is not NULL
    drop table #rowsWithRandomCharsNrs;

--generate with recursion 50 rows, with an id and a random length for the e-mail address
with 
baseRowsWithEmailLength as (
    select 1 as idMail, round(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 60 + 1,0) as strLength
    union all
    select idMail + 1 as idMail, round(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 60 + 1,0) as strLength
    from baseRowsWithEmailLength 
    where idMail < 50
)
--generate with recursion a random number (indexChar) for every char in the string, which is an id to join with the table allowedChar
,rowsWithRandomCharsNrs as(
    select idMail, strLength, 1 as idchar,  round(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * (@countallowedChars-1) +1,0) as indexChar
    from baseRowsWithEmailLength
    union all
    select idMail, strLength, idchar + 1 as idchar,  round(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) *(@countallowedChars-1) +1,0) as indexChar
    from rowsWithRandomCharsNrs
    where idchar < strLength
)


select *
into #rowsWithRandomCharsNrs
from rowsWithRandomCharsNrs


SELECT idMail  
      ,concat(left(mailRandStr, firstMailPartLength),aspc.asChar,RIGHT(mailRandStr, StrLength - firstMailPartLength), '@', ed.domain) as Mail
FROM(
    SELECT idMail
          ,strLength
          ,firstMailPartLength
          ,mailRandStr
          --generate a random number to join a random Domain and specialchar
          ,round(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * (@countDomains-1) +1,0) as idDomain
          ,round(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * (@countallowedSpecialChars-1) +1,0) as idSpecialChar
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT
               idMail
              ,StrLength
              ,round(StrLength * 0.75,0) as firstMailPartLength 
              --concat all chars to a single string via for xml path
              ,(
                 select ''+ac.aChar
                 from #rowsWithRandomCharsNrs sub
                 join #allowedChar ac on sub.indexChar = ac.id
                 where sub.idMail = m.idMail
                 FOR XML PATH('')
              )as mailRandStr
        FROM #rowsWithRandomCharsNrs m
    ) sub
)sub
left join #emailDomain ed on sub.idDomain = ed.id
left join #allowedSpecialChar aspc on sub.idSpecialChar  = aspc.id
```

Do you haven any questions? I help you.

Comment: Thank you Alex, it is working as expected :) Also, I have added 'OPTION (MAXRECURSION 2000)' in the query (i.e. to restrict the limit of loops to specific number) to generates thousands & millions of Email Ids.  select *
into #rowsWithRandomCharsNrs
from rowsWithRandomCharsNrs
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 2000) Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to do this using SQL, try one of the following approaches...

```
DECLARE @randomString VARCHAR(255)
SELECT
  @randomString = CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), NEWID())
PRINT @randomString
```

OR

```
DECLARE @Length INT = 25
PRINT LEFT(REPLACE(NEWID(), '-', ''), @Length)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `CROSS JOIN` with `NEWID()` to generate a large quantity of email addresses. This one generates 30k+ emails at a time until it reaches or exceeds the target count - takes about one second to hit 1019304 email addresses (demo: http://rextester.com/GJS41165)

```
DECLARE @targetCount INT = 1000000

CREATE TABLE #emailTableTemp (fakeEmail VARCHAR(100))

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM #emailTableTemp) < @targetCount
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #emailTableTemp
    SELECT CONCAT(t2.prefix,t1.email) AS fakeEmail FROM 
    (VALUES ('aol.com'),('att.net'),('comcast.net'),('facebook.com'),('gmail.com'),('gmx.com'),('googlemail.com'),('google.com'),('hotmail.com'),('hotmail.co.uk'),('mac.com'),('me.com'),('mail.com'),('msn.com'),('live.com'),('sbcglobal.net'),('verizon.net'),('yahoo.com'),('yahoo.co.uk'),('email.com'),('fastmail.fm'),('games.com'),('gmx.net'),('hush.com'),('hushmail.com'),('icloud.com'),('iname.com'),('inbox.com'),('lavabit.com'),('love.com '),('outlook.com'),('pobox.com'),('protonmail.com'),('rocketmail.com'),('safe-mail.net'),('wow.com '),('ygm.com '),('ymail.com'),('zoho.com'),('yandex.com'),('bellsouth.net'),('charter.net'),('cox.net'),('earthlink.net'),('juno.com'),('btinternet.com'),('virginmedia.com'),('blueyonder.co.uk'),('freeserve.co.uk'),('live.co.uk'),('ntlworld.com'),('o2.co.uk'),('orange.net'),('sky.com'),('virgin.net'),('wanadoo.co.uk'),('bt.com'),('sina.com'),('sina.cn'),('qq.com'),('naver.com'),('hanmail.net'),('daum.net'),('nate.com'),('yahoo.co.jp'),('yahoo.co.kr'),('yahoo.co.id'),('yahoo.co.in'),('yahoo.com.sg'),('yahoo.com.ph'),('163.com'),('126.com'),('aliyun.com'),('foxmail.com'),('hotmail.fr'),('live.fr'),('laposte.net'),('yahoo.fr'),('wanadoo.fr'),('orange.fr'),('gmx.fr'),('sfr.fr'),('neuf.fr'),('free.fr'),('gmx.de'),('hotmail.de'),('live.de'),('online.de'),('t-online.de '),('web.de'),('yahoo.de'),('libero.it'),('virgilio.it'),('hotmail.it'),('aol.it'),('tiscali.it'),('alice.it'),('live.it'),('yahoo.it'),('email.it'),('tin.it'),('poste.it'),('teletu.it'),('mail.ru'),('rambler.ru'),('yandex.ru'),('ya.ru'),('list.ruhotmail.be'),('live.be'),('skynet.be'),('voo.be'),('tvcablenet.be'),('telenet.be'),('hotmail.com.ar'),('live.com.ar'),('yahoo.com.ar'),('fibertel.com.ar'),('speedy.com.ar'),('arnet.com.ar'),('yahoo.com.mx'),('live.com.mx'),('hotmail.es,yahoo.com.ar'),('fibertel.com.ar'),('speedy.com.ar'),('arnet.com.ar'),('yahoo.com.mx'),('live.com.mx'),('hotmail.es'),('hotmail.com.mx'),('prodigy.net.mx'),('yahoo.com.br'),('hotmail.com.br'),('outlook.com.br'),('uol.com.br'),('bol.com.br'),('terra.com.br'),('ig.com.br'),('itelefonica.com.br'),('r7.com'),('zipmail.com.br'),('globo.com'),('globomail.com'),('oi.com.br')) t1(email)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES 
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),        
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),        
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),        
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),
        (CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@')),(CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()),'-',''),'@'))
        ) t2(prefix)
END

SELECT COUNT(1) FROM #emailTableTemp
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM #emailTableTemp ORDER BY fakeEmail

DROP TABLE #emailTableTemp
```